# Two mutually exclusive many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, many-to-many

Imagine an online shop. You have goods. Some goods have size, some don't. I've got an `orders` table:

```
id int not null,
...
```

`orders_products` table:

```
order_id int not null,
product_id int null,
size_id int null,
...
```

`products` table:

```
id int not null,
...
```

`sizes` table:

```
id int not null,
product_id int not null,
...
```

Right now either `product_id` or `size_id` is not null. In other words, primary key is `order_id` + (`product_id` xor `size_id`). Not both.

In Django's terms that would be:

```py
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=OrderProduct, related_name='orders')
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, through=OrderProduct, related_name='orders')
    ...
```

At least that's what I have right now. But I don't like having two mutually exclusive foreign keys in `orders_products` table. Or two attributes in `Order` model. One of which (`sizes`) is probably redundant.

So, I probably have to remove `sizes` attribute from the `Order` model. Is that it? Or should I make `product_id` not null in `orders_products` table? And have `size_id` only when the product comes in different sizes? Any other suggestions?

I've marked the question with `django`, `python`, `postgresql` tags. That's because those are what I'm using right now. But I'm not stuck on any particular language, but SQL.

**UPD** I just realized I have denormalized `sizes` table. There are mostly `S`, `M`, `L` sizes there.

And right now I see four options:

1. The way I have it now. `Order.products` and `Order.sizes` appear to work. They get to nonintersecting sets of products. But there is a possibility for inconsistencies in database (both `orders_products.product_id` and `orders_products.size_id` are set or not set).
2. What suggested [maverick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48011069/52499): generic foreign keys.
3. Normalize `sizes` table (many-to-many relationship):

   `products` table:

   ```
   id int not null,
   ...
   ```

   `products_sizes` table:

   ```
   product_id int not null,
   size_id int not null,
   ...
   ```

   `sizes` table:

   ```
   id int not null,
   ...
   ```

   Then, having `orders_products` table this way:

   ```
   order_id int not null,
   product_id int null not null,
   size_id int null,
   ...
   ```

   kind of makes more sense. Well, there's still possibility for `orders_products.size_id` being null for products having size. And for `orders_products.size_id` being linked to a size the product doesn't have.

   Generic foreign keys won't most likely do in case of normalized tables.
4. Extract `product_variants` table (what consumer basically buys):

   `products`:

   ```
   id int not null,
   ...
   ```

   `sizes`:

   ```
   id int not null,
   ...
   ```

   `product_variants`:

   ```
   id int not null,
   product id int not null,
   size_id int null
   ```

   `orders_products`:

   ```
   order_id int not null,
   productvariant_id int not null,
   amount int not null
   ```

   The statement about generic foreign keys seems to hold here as well.

Which one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to settle on my last idea. Normalize `sizes` table, by creating intermediate `productvariants` table, which holds entities representing things customers buy.

`orders` table:

```
id int not null,
...
```

`orders_productvariants` table:

```
order_id int not null,
productvariant_id int not null,
...
```

`productvariants` table:

```
id int not null,
product_id int not null,
size_id int not null,
...
```

`products` table:

```
id int not null,
...
```

`sizes` table:

```
id int not null,
...
```

Additionally, I have a size with empty name, for items that have no size.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Generic Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) for `OrderProduct` on `Product` and `ProductSize`. It stores the object type and object id which provides mutual exclusivity among two Foreign keys.

```
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    ...
    limit = models.Q(app_label = 'app', model = 'Product') | models.Q(app_label = 'app', model = 'ProductSize')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to = limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: Do you think it's worth it? What are advantages/disadvantages? I might need natural keys down the road (for fixtures/serialization). Can't use `GenericForeignKey` fields with filters. They don't appear in `ModelForm`s. `on_delete=cascade` for `GenericForeignKey` fields with reverse relations. Worse performance. Probably these are of not much concern to me, at least now. Probably more possibilities for inconsistencies in database. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Advantages: `GenericForeignKey` will remove redundancy from your database. Suggestion to `GenericForeignKey` is totally based on mutual exclusivity. Answering your concerns over `GenericForeignKey`: You can use filters on Product like `OrderProduct.objects.filter(Q(products__id=1) | Q(product_sizes__product__id=1))`. You can add a custom field in ModelForm to load a list from both the tables. But yes performance is worse. This is the trade-off between performance and redundant data.

Comment: It will also handle your concern for a product being linked with a size it doesn't have or a product size being null for a product having size. As you will be storing `Product` object when the product has no sizes and you will be storing `ProductSize` object when a product has size. You wont require 2 `ManytoManyFields` in order table for non intersecting sets.

Comment: But generic foreign keys seem to be of no use if I normalize the tables (see options 3 and 4 in my question). Which is probably better (have normalized tables until you have a reason not to) and makes me think generic foreign keys are not good for my case (they seem to be good when you want to link to several tables, which is not the case with normalized tables). What do you say?

Comment: Your 4th option looks good. You eventually changed `ProductSize` to `ProductVarient` which makes more sense by name. At first I thought the same that foreign key with only `ProductSizes` doesn&#39;t seem right by name but eventually that is what a consumer buys.